# HTML5 Video "Black Screen" on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, html5-video

I'm building a website that has videos embedded within them. This website needs to cater for iPad users as well but I'm having trouble with the ol' `video` tag at the moment. I have a video that plays fine in browsers but not on an iPad unfortunately.

I'm just getting a black screen with the iPad, and no error message to speak of.

Here is my code for the video:

```
<video id="movie" width="790" height="250" controls >
    <source src="anim/intro.ipad.mp4"  type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    <source src="anim/intro.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
    <source src="anim/intro.theora.ogv"  type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
<script>
    var v = document.getElementById("movie");
    v.onclick = function() {
        if (v.paused) {
            v.play();
        } else {
            v.pause();
        }
    };
</script>
```

The videos were all created following tutorials about HTML5 video. They were all encoded using preferred iPad settings on Miro Video converter.

Just incase this matters (I'm not sure it will) I'm testing the video on an iPad simulator.

No matter what I do, I just can't get the video to play:

[image: on iPad Simulator]

Comment: i think controlling html5 audio and video from javascript doesnt work in mobile safari. it can work in UIWebView if you set mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction to NO.

Comment: It's a website that needs to be compatible with iPads, it's not an app that uses a UIWebView

Comment: @at0mzk: false they work just fine. I have it working on mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you got the encoding right?
Try this to test it:

```
<video src="anim/intro.ipad.mp4" controls>  
      Your browser does not support the video element.  
</video>
```

Comment: I did this, and the video displayed as a black screen again, it didn't show the message "Your browser does not support the video element."

Comment: Well, it is an encoding issue then. This code really works if your encoding is right.

Comment: Just to clean up an old question, the solution that worked for me was to encode the video directly from Quicktime 7 which allows you to export for mobile. This automatically preset the correct settings for display on devices such as the iPad. This question helped me identify that it was indeed encoding that was my issue.

Comment: though already solved: you should stick to Apple's manual on this. The most common error is not using baseline profile for encoding the video

Answer (score 1):

is your .htaccess file serving up the particular video files correctly?

> Ensure your server is using the correct mime-types. Firefox will not play the Ogg video if the mime-type is wrong. Place these lines in your .htaccess file to send the correct mime-types to browsers

```
AddType video/ogg  .ogv
AddType video/mp4  .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Reference:
[Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody)

Also, are you modifying the video element by using positioning? I've found that this creates this black video screen too.

Comment: Hi @Federico, yeah I've added this in. It was an encoding error as @gnur suggested, I used quicktime to export it properly for iPhone instead of Miro and it was fine