# HTML5 video playback on the iPad?

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, video, html5-video

I'm developing a web app, and having trouble with HTML5 video for iPad. This code works fine every where else, not iPad. I just get a video frame, a black box. The HTML is generated in javascript, it is not hardcoded per se.

```
<video preload="true" src="places/video.mp4" class="c1" id="it" height="480" width="385" controls="">
</video>
```

Anyone know what could be wrong? (Videos are encoded using handbrake CLI and ffmpeg2theora as specified in Dive Into HTML5).

I think the issue is that it isn't http://serverlocation/places/video.ext. How would I alter it to look like that (with no guarantee that I know server location.) Part of me doubts this because images are served without the http:// and they work fine.

Comment: Are the videos using the Theora codec? The iPad does not support Theora. They should be in h.264. See http://www.tipb.com/2010/05/01/h264-ascendant-apples-noflash-notheora-gamble-pay/

Comment: There is both h.264/aac and ogg theora. iPad only sees the first source which is mp4. I disabled the type for mp4, because it works in http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html (last example) for android too. (haven't tested on android yet)

Comment: Silly question, but video.mp4 does exist, right? Try adding `type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'` to the .mp4 `<source>` tag.

Comment: Yes, of course!

Type doesn't help :/

Do you think the fact it isn't loaded on pageload is an issue?

Comment: Thanks. That narrowed it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know the problem. iPad chokes when presented with multiple `<source>` tags. What you can do (to do it simply) is use jQuery to add/remove objects.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="movie-wrapper">
  <div id="webkit-wrapper">
    <video width="480" height="360" controls="controls" src="places/video.mp4"></video>
  </div>
  <div id="other-wrapper">
    <!-- Do your video in a new wrapper for all others -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  if($.browser.webkit) {
    $('#other-wrapper').remove();
  } else {
    $('#webkit-wrapper').remove();
  }
});
```

Ideally, you're going to have a conditional for every major browser since you need at least three types of video for complete compatibility. But something like this should resolve the iPad webkit choke.

**Edit**
Rereading your comment, I want to make sure of something – that you have `controls="controls"` on the video element as above. From everything I've read, iPad requires that to enable playback. Otherwise, you get... a black screen.

And you might also look into whether there's an encoding problem, per [HTML5 Video "Black Screen" on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077390/html5-video-black-screen-on-ipad)

**Edit**
Other considerations:
Webserver may not be reporting the filetype properly (you can check this in the error console if it transfers with a  warning about type)

If a poster is loading, try directly accessing the link to the mp4 video (see if quicktime plays it in the browser).

Other than that, I have no idea – there's going to continue to be miscommunication of facts unless you post a link to your page with the non-working example.

Comment: This is a great answer, very detailed, however it does not work.               edit: actually, let me try again. edit2: yeah it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I just completely removed the ogv source, and tried again. Still shows a black box.

Comment: Hm, your edit is interesting. I have checked and it is a browser rendering as I have have entered it in js as controls ='controls', which is fine in every other browser

Comment: What happens if you set a poster?

Comment: I found the error!! Thank you so much for being so helpful - I tried to load the video resource without any html (just the src url), and I got Byte_Range_Error_Message. I think it is a server side issue, but i'm not sure how to fix it. I am using Node.js.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2590775?start=0&tstart=0 | http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922330